# NPM Plugin For Formatting/Checking Arbitrary Language

Tags: npm, static-analysis, prettier

I'm working with a language (XQuery) that doesn't have a large development community and doesn't have a lot of options for static code analysis. But I'm wondering if there are enough generic solutions out there in NPM that will provide some mileage.

One issue is formatting. I'm familiar with Prettier, but it looks like all of the plugins out there are specific to certain languages. Can Prettier be configured for arbitrary languages? If so, how can that be done? If not, are there any other plugins that could help?

I've also got access to the grammar file, so I wonder if any plugins to make use of that.